# how to setup dynamically , without compose, multiple django docker containers with postgres containers for each domain on the fly

Tags: docker

How does one deal with creating multiple django docker containers and their related postgresql docker containers for N domains.

I have a local dnsserver to mimic production and i setup allow *.test.com and test.com to point to my 127.0.0.1

I have created a docker network bridge for all the docker containers running under this project so that I can reach them by name of the docker.

So when a client/tenant  register for a system, say company "mycomp", I create a django docker container called mycomp_web, it is reachable at mycomp.test.com,
Ngnix parses the domain and maps the revers_proxy to find mycomp_web django container. This works well. But now I need to switch from sqlite to postgresql.
So i need to also create a postgresql container for each domain. So it would be something like mycomp_db.

Now the real question is ? how do I point my django instance to the right postgres container (using name of that container). Up until now I was using docker names to find the containers.

How would you set the database entry in the settings.py of django

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'erp', 
        'USER': 'erp_user',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1', 
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
```

How would one change `HOST` and `PORT`  to find the postgres docker container that matches to that domain?

So if I register a new domain like mycomp2, I ll will have mycomp2_web (django container and mycomp2_db(postgresql container) and django container will be able to find the postgres container that belongs to that domain.

Maybe using docker py helps, I can get the db container by name (mycomp_db) get its attributes port and ip and use them in settings.py of django container. This, however, seems a bit hacky.

Thanks

Comment: Put the docker hostname in the config file rather than 127.0.0.1? Set an environment variable? It's not clear where the problem is here, sorry.

Comment: So as I mentioned there will be N containers ( django and postgresql) for each tenant. 
First postgresql container for the newly registered tenant needs to run. Then I need to get the host port of that docker somehow so I can pass it to the environment of the django container for that tenant. I do not specify the host port myself since there is going to be a lot of postgresql containers.  I do not want to manage the state of the ports.
But docker does not have a command that returns the port, you need to write a awk / grep etc to read the port that we created.  That is one of the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Richard pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78054277/how-to-setup-dynamically-without-compose-multiple-django-docker-containers-wi#comment137604596_78054277) you should simply use the container name of the respective postgres container as the hostname in the `settings.py`, i.e., for `mycomp2_web`:

```py
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'erp', 
        'USER': 'erp_user',
        'PASSWORD': '123',
        'HOST': 'mycomp2_db', 
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
```

`mycomp2_db` will by resolved to the postgres containers internal IP address by the internal docker DNS. On *that* IP address the postgres process will be listening on always to same port - so no need to change this dynamically.

---

What you were trying instead according to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78054277/how-to-setup-dynamically-without-compose-multiple-django-docker-containers-wi#comment137606362_78054277) was to always expose the port of the database containers to the host - which for multiple hosts would require different randomly assigned ports. But you don't need to expose the ports to the host in the first place and can rather just use the internal IP address of the container instead - which can also be easily resolved by just using the container host name as described above.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed I did not know name would resolve to an Ip from inside django. That makes total sense. No need to parse the port.